# vBulletin Version 4.2.2 hides threads

Tags: vbulletin

I have a regular vBulletin Version 4.2.2 forum.

When I look at the list of the forums Forum A says that is has 10 threads.
When I click on the forum only 3 threads are displayed.
I checked the setting "display from the beginning" so that is not the issue.
Not all forums have this issue. Only some.

May be there is a setting somewhere that hides old threads but I can not find it. Did plenty of googling but no exact solution.

If you have time to look at the actual problem then links are [here](http://forums.coastsidefishingclub.com/forum.php).

Look at marine Electronics. It says Threads: 15
Click on [Marin Electronics](http://forums.coastsidefishingclub.com/forumdisplay.php?54-Marine-Electronics)
only 3 threads shown.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this permissions:

```
http://forums.coastsidefishingclub.com/admincp/forumpermission.php?do=modify
```

or

ACP > Forums & Moderators > Forum Manager > Edit Forum > Moderation Options

check this